# Routing all image requests with Sinatra Fake Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra

I am relatively new to Sinatra and fake requests.  I was wondering if using Sinatra there is way (regardless of the url) to redirect all requests for images (jpg,png,gifs, etc) such that all requests fetch the same object.

Basically when the app looks for a file http://thissite/image.jpg or http://thatsite/fish.gif all of them will be rerouted to the same fake request file regardless of the url.

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Just serving the same image for each request on any image?

Comment: @Sirl33tname precisely

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to just use a regex route (http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes)

```
get %r{.*\.(jpg|png|gif)} do
  p 'return your image here'
end
```